# Progress Bar For Long Running Query

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, progress-bar

I'm using VS 2005 with C#. I have a query that takes about 25 to 30 seconds and show the result with crystal report.
I want to show progress bar while query executing.
My situation is same with the [Progress bar for long running task in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759386/progress-bar-for-long-running-task-in-c-sharp)
I follow the steps in that post but the progress bar is blank.
Please see my code and advise what is needed.

```
private string orderby, startDate, endDate, brandName;
ReportDocument rpt;
private BackgroundWorker bgw;
private void SearchFunction()
 {            
        orderby = cboOrderBy.Text;
        startDate = txtFromDate.Text;
        endDate = txtToDate.Text;
        brandName = txtBrandName.Text;
        bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgw_ProgressChanged);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
            dt = obj1.getData1(orderby, startDate, endDate, brandName);          
}

void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
 }

 void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
            //After completing the job.
            MessageBox.Show(@"Finished");
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //some code for crystal report like
                rpt = new myReport();                
                rpt.SetDataSource(dt);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
                crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No record found !");
            }
 }
```

Comment: Adding the ReportProgress after assign data to datatable in DoWork method not give the desired output. The progress bar start filling after long time due to long query execution time.

Comment: And what is the desired output? Updating the progress is your responsibility, and since you are just calling one function, the only option you have is @Niels Filter **Method 2**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Method 1: Showing Progress (0% to 100%)

Simply call `ReportProgress` in the `DoWork` method.

```
void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   int percentComplete = 0;
   // Do work and let the work increment percepercentComplete as it's busy.
   bgw.ReportProgress(percentComplete);
}
```

[image]

This will means that you must change the `getData1` method needs to report progress in chunks as it's busy.

#### Method 2: No Progress percentage (simply shows it's busy)

If you don't want to change `getData1`, set the `IsInderminate` property to true on your `ProgressBar`.

```
progressBar1.IsInderminate = true;
```

[image]

Then you don't need the `bgw_ProgressChanged` method at all. `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted` are sufficient.

### EDIT:

Apologies, I assumed WPF. For.NET 2 you're using WinForms?

**WinForms:** In the designer, on the `ProgressBar`, change `Style` to `Marquee`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I can't find IsInderminate property, is it because I am using .Net framework 2 ? How can I edit getData1 method as it is just a sql statement and use dataAdapter.fill method, not include any looping or many process.

Comment: My apologies, I assumed WPF. Now assuming WinForms (.NET 2)? See the updated answer: In the designer, change ProgressBar Style to `Marquee`.

Comment: Hi Niels Filter, thanks a lot for your help. I changed the progress bar style to Marquee now. I still want to know how to use ReportProgress without looping. All I found on the net is using the looping and my function has no loop but has only one query and fill the result into data table using data adapter. Pls kindly suggest.

Comment: If you want to call `ReportProgress` without looping, another option would be to split the `getData1` into multiple parts or queries, then call `ReportProgress` after every query.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

you're not actually reporting any progress.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Agreed.  OP I guess would need to call this from inside `getData()`

Comment: @MickyDuncan indeed, hoping the correct usage would be an exercise for the OP. I do wish people would read tutorials before asking "do it for me-esque" questions here. Sad when hand-holding is how you get to be the accepted answer these days.

Comment: I hear you buddy.  SO policy is that you can give them just enough to put them on their way anyway. :) _"Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful"_.  Anyway +1